# Call a method from a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, c#-7.0, c#-8.0

I'll to make a method that parse an input from a console application and return the value if the `TryParse` passes, else keep asking. I'll use that same method for a `char` and `int` variables. Because of that I've written this method.

```cs
int a = GetInput<int>("a");
char operation = GetInput<char>("operation");
int b = GetInput<int>("b");

private static TResult GetInput<TResult>(string variable)
{
    Console.Write($"Enter {variable}: ");

    if (TResult.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out TResult input)) 
//              ^^^^^^^^
    {
        return input;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
    return ReadInteger<TResult>(variable);
}
```

However I've got this error on the line that calls the `TryParse`:

> `TResult` is a type parameter, which is not valid in the given context

How could I solve this? I know that `TResult` don't have a method `TryParse` but I don't know how I make the compiler belive that there will always a `TryParse`. Can I solve this with pattern machting?

**P.S.:** I'm making a demo of C#8 so C#8 is welcome.

Comment: I downvoted for the simple fact that I have no idea from where did you get the idea that this would work in c# 8

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: new version comes with new features... (litle asside it's possible in TypeScript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way of doing this without using reflection, at the moment. It's possible that in the future, C# *may* introduce a way of constraining type parameters in terms of what operators, static methods and constructors they have - but there's nothing in the C# 8 previews (and I'm not expecting it to be introduced in C# 8).